# How can i remove fields with value 0 in Json API response

Tags: c#, .net, api

Hello i'm developing an API in .net c# for returning a content of a folder How can i remove
"subFolderCount": 0,
"contentCount": 0
these fields from response with value 0. i have declared these fields as

```
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int SubFolderCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int ContentCount { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the properties as nullable and make sure a value of zero is not being assigned to them:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int? SubFolderCount { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int? ContentCount { get; set; }
```